# CSS flex box last space removed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

By setting the `display` of an item to `flex` I am finding the last space is removed from a text string so.

```
<div class="has_flex"> Some text <a href="link">Link</a></div>
```

Becomes

```
<div class="has_flex"> Some text<a href="link">Link</a></div>
```

```css
.has_flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="no__flex">Some text <a href="link">Link</a></div>
<div class="has_flex">Some text <a href="link">Link</a></div>
```

I have wrapped the text in a span and that makes no difference.

Comment: Not an answer maybe but a workaround; `&nbsp;`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a problem with the question or in actual code as mm759 pointed out but it seems to work with proper HTML formatting https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/37pyefku/

Comment: this is more what is happening https://jsfiddle.net/4t9wwy55/

Comment: &nbsp; does work but I want to avoid trying find every occurrence where this is needed.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space. It should only be used to avoid line breaks between certain words. Do not use it as a way to insert non-collapsible whitespace. It's not semantic.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

#### Reason

When you don't use `display: flex`, the your layout becomes something like

```
<div class="has_flex"><!--
  --><anonymous style="display: inline">Some text </anonymous><!--
  --><a         style="display: inline">Link</a><!--
--></div>
```

The text (including the space at the end) is wrapped inside an [anonymous inline box](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous):

> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline element.

However, Flexbox layout blockifies the [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items):

> The [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) value of a [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) is [blockified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#blockify): if
>   the specified [`display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) of an in-flow child of an element
>   generating a [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) is an inline-level value, it computes
>   to its block-level equivalent.

Then, the layout will be like

```
<div class="has_flex"><!--
  --><anonymous style="display: block">Some text </anonymous><!--
  --><a         style="display: block">Link</a><!--
--></div>
```

This might not seem directly related, but it's relevant because of [the `white-space` processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model):

> Then, the block container's inlines are laid out. [...] As each line
>   is laid out, [...]
>
> 3. If a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has `white-space`
>      set to `normal`, `nowrap`, or `pre-line`, **it is also removed**.

So when the anonymous element and the link were both inline, the space was at the middle of a line. If you had multiple spaces they would collapse into a single one, but not disappear completely.

However, when you use flexbox, each flex item has its own lines, and the space is therefore at the end of a line. So it's removed.

Note this problem is not specific of flexbox, spaces at the end of an inline-block are also removed.

```css
.in-blo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="inline">Some text </span><a href="link">Link</a></div>
<div><span class="in-blo">Some text </span><a href="link">Link</a></div>
```

However, in that case you can just move the space outside the inline-block. In flexbox that's not possible, because anonymous flex items that contain only white space are not rendered.

#### Solution

If you want to preserve the space, you can set `white-space` to another value. `white-space: pre-wrap` will allow text wrapping, `white-space: pre` won't.

```css
.has_flex {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="no__flex">Some text <a href="link">Link</a></div>
<div class="has_flex">Some text <a href="link">Link</a></div>
```

Comment: a model answer!

Comment: nice explanation. However, `white-space: pre-wrap` isn't always suitable; e.g. you wouldn't want new lines due to line wrapping to be displayed on the page. An alternate solution is to wrap your text inside a `<span>`. E.g., `<div class="has_flex"><span>Some text <a href="link">Link</a></span></div>`

Comment: Thanks, the ```white-space: pre-wrap;``` saved my life :)

Answer (score -6):

The end of the `div` is missing. So, strange things can happen. This could be what you want:

```
<div class="has_flex"> Some text <a href="link">Link</a></div>
```