# Display flex is omitting spaces around the text value given in a span tag

Tags: javascript, css, sass, flexbox

I have created a demo, passing value with **spaces** around, defined two elements (p tag) in the HTML file, one with flex property and another without. An element with flex property showing the value without space in the HTML file and another one is simply displaying the actual value including space.

**How to display actual value coming from JS file in the element with flex property?**

UPDATE:
**I want to understand why is the flex property removing the space from the value?**

```js
var value = " is ";
document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = value;
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p class="flex">
 <span>This</span>
 <span id='value'>value</span>
 <span>hello</span>
</p>

<p>
 <span>This</span>
 <span id='value1'>value</span>
 <span>hello</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more in-depth answer, please check out [@Orial's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334882/5625547) post.
<sup>[CSS flex box last space removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325039/css-flex-box-last-space-removed)</sup>

---

The [white-space processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model) tells us:

> If a **space** (U+0020) at the end of a line has white-space set to normal, nowrap, or pre-line, **it is also removed**.

To prevent this, use `white-space: pre-wrap;`:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var value = " is ";
document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = value;
document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = value;
```

```css
.flex{
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="flex">
 <span>This</span>
 <span id='value'>value</span>
 <span>hello</span>
</p>

<p>
 <span>This</span>
 <span id='value1'>value</span>
 <span>hello</span>
</p>
```