# How do I keep whitespace between text nodes and elements in a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a feature to highlight search results on a page at runtime by wrapping text in `<mark>` tags. The site is using Vuetify JS so almost every element is a flex container, and (as expected) the whitespace gets collapsed between text nodes and elements in a flex container.

When I highlight part of a text node in a flex container, the spaces around the highlighted area disappear, and the element looks broken.

Example:

```css
button {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button>Add to <mark>cart</mark> now</button>

<p>(Should say "Add to <mark>cart</mark> now")<p>
```

Is there any way to preserve the whitespace between the `<mark>` element and the text adjacent text nodes?
Update: Since this is interacting with a Vuetify app, I'm hoping for some styles I can apply to the injected `<mark>` element, rather than the parent flex container.

I've tried adding pseudo-elements to the `::before`/`::after` with `content(' ')` to no avail.

Comment: use `column-gap`

Comment: *The site is using Vuetify JS so almost every element is a flex container* --> this is what you need to fix because making everything flexbox is wrong. Read this: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS flex box last space removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325039/css-flex-box-last-space-removed)

Comment: The answers about white-space: pre & pre-wrap are great to know, but unfortunately in this case with a 3rd-party framework like Vuetify, I can't blanket-add a white-space rule to any element with matching text without causing other problems. (Previously-unseen white space will get rendered at the start/end of the innerText, for instance). Is there anything I can do just to the `mark` element I'm injecting?

Comment: It's weird that a vue framework would have CSS opinions like putting display: flex on everything. I believe that button elements aren't allowed to have display flex. I've had to put a span/div in the button to apply the flex properties. But also, in general flex parents should have child elements and not just plain text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464067/flex-grid-layouts-not-working-on-button-or-fieldset-elements

Comment: It's handy for aligning icons on your buttons, but the framework should wrap your label text in a span or something, agreed. I think I'll end up just identifying the problematic spots and wrapping things in spans, rather than hacking on the framework's styles

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve the white space for visual purposes, then `gap: 3px` is a simple way to create space between items in a flex container.

Edit: updated answer based on @herrstrietzel's suggestion to use `0.2em` instead of pixels, so the spacing scales with font size increase (Codepen demonstration in comments).

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.2em;

}
```

```html
<button>Add to <mark>cart</mark> now</button>

<p>(Should say "Add to <mark>cart</mark> now")<p>
```

Comment: That won't scale to the font size, however. If the button font size is 2rem then the 3px spacing will not be proportionate.

Comment: @hjalmardev: replace 3px with a relative unit like `0.2em` and it will work pretty well: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/KKRzvqR). Another benefit of this approach it will only address flex elements (... that shouldn't use flex - as commented by Temani Afif)

Comment: @herrstrietzel I edited my answer to include your suggestion, and thank you for the Codepen demonstration too!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Wrap it in pre tags and style it to inherit the body font</s>

Add `white-space:pre` to the button rule.

<s>Edit: p tags work too.</s>

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre;  
}
```

```html
<button>Add to <mark>cart</mark> now</button>

<p>(Should say "Add to <mark>cart</mark> now")
  <p>
```

Comment: you probably want `pre-wrap` just in case here.

Answer (score -1):

Use non-breaking space `&nbsp;` instead of the two regular whitespace characters around the `<mark>...</mark>` tags.

```css
button {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button>Add to&nbsp;<mark>cart</mark>&nbsp;now</button>

<p>(Should say "Add to <mark>cart</mark> now")<p>
```